# How to make sure script runs at least once per month

Tags: macos

Since our wifi password changes every month, I would like to automate changing the password on my Mac.

Here's the command I am using to change the password

```
networksetup -setairportnetwork en0 <MY_WIFI_SSSID> <MY_WIFI_PASSWORD>
```

Now I would like to make sure it runs after every first of the month. Even if the Mac was sleeping or turned off. I was thinking to store the hash of the password to some file and run a cron job every minute. As long as the hash is the same as the computed one nothing should happen, otherwise the new wifi password is set and the new hash is stored to the file. But I think there might be a better solution using launchd to run the script after login, wake from sleep (unlock), an at the start of the month in case the laptop was still running at midnight.

Comment: how do you plan on obtaining the new password? do you know the new password before it takes effect?